# Efficient query for counting multiple relationships of multiple entities

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using MS SQL Server, I'd like to count the number of entities to which each of several entities is related. Let's say my schema looks something like this:

```
foo (
  id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
)

thing1 (
  id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
)

thing2 (
  id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
)

thingN (
  id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
)
```

with join tables

```
foo_thing1 (
  foo_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
  thing1_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
)
```

etc.

there might be 2 thingNs, or 10, or some other number- I want something that works well even when there are quite a few. If there was just one Foo, a possible solution looks like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT foo_thing1.thing1_id),
       COUNT(DISTINCT foo_thing2.thing2_id),
       COUNT(DISTINCT foo_thing3.thing3_id),
       COUNT(DISTINCT foo_thing4.thing4_id,
FROM foo
LEFT JOIN foo_thing1 ON foo_thing1.thing1_id = thing1.id
LEFT JOIN foo_thing2 ON foo_thing2.thing2_id = thing2.id
LEFT JOIN foo_thing3 ON foo_thing3.thing3_id = thing3.id
LEFT JOIN foo_thing4 ON foo_thing4.thing4_id = thing4.id
GROUP BY foo.id
HAVING foo.id = '12341234-1234-12341234-1234'
```

However, I'm not sure this is efficient. What if the Foo is related to a lot of thing2s and a lot of thing3s - am I getting far too many rows, and then hiding it with DISTINCT?

Further complicating things, I actually want to count the relationships of more than one foo at once. Ideally I'd like to do it by arbitrary where clause, but if necessary I can just supply a list of ids such that WHERE/HAVING foo.id IN (x, y, z). From there, though, how should I determine all the cardinalities? :(

UNION ALL is one option, since my goal in combining these queries is to save database roundtrip latency. But I suspect that the parse time of multiple SELECTs means it can't be *the* most efficient way...

Comment: Hello.  Is this maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855373/sql-server-select-distinct ?

Comment: Not really the same thing, no. That poster wants to count ordered columns, for a single entity.

Comment: Sure.  I liked the ability to find those Distinct pairs (or triplets, etc) .  So is it better to say you are looking to find all pairs automatically, without knowing them in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work the way you expect:

```
SELECT foo.id,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM foo_thing1 WHERE foo_thing1.foo_id = foo.id),
    (SELECT count(*) FROM foo_thing2 WHERE foo_thing2.foo_id = foo.id),
    (SELECT count(*) FROM foo_thing3 WHERE foo_thing3.foo_id = foo.id),
    ...
FROM foo
WHERE foo.id IN (1, 2, 3, 7, ...);
```

Comment: This looks promising! I'll try it out when I get to work tomorrow and accept the answer. Are there any interesting caveats to the use of subqueries here?

Comment: Hopefully you've got these foo_thingN.foo_id columns indexed, otherwise the query will get really slow. Apart from this, you shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: Yes, they're indexed. The query ended up working well.